# Ubuntu 14.04 and Wireless problem using Dell Vostro 3560

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

I'm a Linux newbie, I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 3560 with Broadcom wireless card. The problem is that I can't use wifi on Ubuntu 14 (also on Ubuntu 13.10). my network indicator show exactly like picture below

[No wireless picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzN3N.png)

Can you help me to solve my problem. Because I'm just a Linux noob, so I greatly appreciate if you guide me step by step... Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)